# Switch Application to Unicode

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, unicode, django-models

My model.py looks like:

```
import csv

with open("organizationTest.txt","rU") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            _, created = Company.objects.get_or_create(
                Name=row[0],
                Site=row[1],
                )
```

"Name" and "Site" are both described in the model!

Whenever I try and run my server I get

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.

How can I switch my application to Unicode strings as it's said or if there is any other way to fix this issue I would love to know!

I would be happy to answer any questions! Thank you in advance!

**EDIT: Here is the full error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "manage.py", line 10, in 
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 312, in execute
>       django.setup()
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/**init**.py", line 18, in setup
>       apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
>       app_config.import_models(all_models)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
>       self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in import_module
>       **import**(name)
>     File "/Users/aghodsib/Desktop/soroush_programming/Python/slik/companies/models.py", line 58, in 
>       description=row[15],
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
>       return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 405, in get_or_create
>       return self.get(**lookup), False
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 328, in get
>       num = len(clone)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 144, in **len**
>       self._fetch_all()
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 965, in _fetch_all
>       self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 238, in iterator
>       results = compiler.execute_sql()
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 837, in execute_sql
>       cursor.execute(sql, params)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
>       return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in **exit**
>       six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 318, in execute
>       return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
>   django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.

Comment: That error isn't coming from Django itself. Please post the full traceback so we can see the issue in context.

Comment: I have added the full error!

Comment: try Name=row[0].decode('UTF-8')

Comment: I get: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 0: invalid continuation byte"

Comment: In that case Name=row[0].decode('cp1252')

Comment: Now I get "UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 20: character maps to <undefined>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be getting characters from an unusual codec.
The source of the csv file should be able to tell you what they are using.
However, you can shift from one codec to another like this:

```
import csv

with open("organizationTest.txt","rU") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            _, created = Company.objects.get_or_create(
                Name=row[0].decode('latin-1').encode('utf8'),
                Site=row[1].decode('latin-1').encode('utf8'),
                )
```

I suggest that you give that a try. If it still doesn't work contact the creator of the csv file.

Comment: Thank you for the help! It does work, but it's almost 150x slower than before. Do you know of how to make it faster?

Comment: Sorry, I don't! It is what it is, but just for the hell of it, I would try separate decode and encode statements just to see if it made a difference. The other option is to get the creator of the csv file to create it in utf-8, saving you the grief.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Python CSV docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples):

> The csv module doesn’t directly support reading and writing Unicode,
>   but it is 8-bit-clean save for some problems with ASCII NUL
>   characters. So you can write functions or classes that handle the
>   encoding and decoding for you as long as you avoid encodings like
>   UTF-16 that use NULs. UTF-8 is recommended.
>
> unicode_csv_reader() below is a generator that wraps csv.reader to
>   handle Unicode CSV data (a list of Unicode strings).

```
import csv

def unicode_csv_reader(unicode_csv_data, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
    # csv.py doesn't do Unicode; encode temporarily as UTF-8:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data),
                            dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
    for row in csv_reader:
        # decode UTF-8 back to Unicode, cell by cell:
        yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]

def utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data):
    for line in unicode_csv_data:
        yield line.encode('utf-8')


with open("organizationTest.txt","rU") as f:
        reader = unicode_csv_reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            _, created = Company.objects.get_or_create(
                Name=row[0],
                Site=row[1],
                )
```

Comment: I get "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 462: ordinal not in range(128)"

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import csv

with open("organizationTest.txt","rU") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            _, created = Company.objects.get_or_create(
                Name=unicode(row[0]),
                Site=unicode(row[1]),
                )
```

Comment: I get: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)"